# How to toggle all el-collapse-items of ElementPlus Vue3 Library with a single button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, element-plus

Using this code, how to expand and collapse.. toggle all el-collapse-items of ElementPlus Vue3 Library with a single button ?

```
<template>
<div class="demo-collapse">
<el-collapse v-model="activeName" accordion>
  <el-collapse-item title="Consistency" name="1">

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const activeName = ref('1')
</script>
```

https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/collapse.html#accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this in the **accordion** mode. As documentations says:

> In accordion mode, only one panel can be expanded at once

To do this, you have to remove the **accordion** prop and change the *activeName* value to an array, just like in the documentation:

```
  const activeNames = ref(['1'])
```

To expand/collapse all items you can create a function that will change the value of **activeNames** to contain all the *names* of *el-collapse-item* components or to be empty, e.g

```
toggleElements() {
  if(activeName.value.length) {
    activeName.value = [];
  } else {
    activeName.value = ['1', '2', '3', ...];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following snippet pls :

```js
const { ref } = Vue

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const items = ref([{id: 1, title: "first", text: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"}, {id: 2, title: "second", text: "bbbbbbbbbbbb"}, {id: 3, title: "third", text: "ccccccccccc"}])
    const activeName = ref([1]);
    const toggleAll = () => {
      activeName.value = activeName.value.length === items.value.length 
        ? [] 
        : items.value.map(i => i.id)
    }
    return { items, activeName, toggleAll };
  },
})
app.use(ElementPlus);
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/element-plus/dist/index.css" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-plus"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <div class="flex justify-space-between mb-4 flex-wrap gap-4">
    <el-button type="primary" text bg @click="toggleAll">toggle all</el-button>
  </div>
  <div class="demo-collapse">
    <el-collapse v-model="activeName" accordion>
      <el-collapse-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :title="item.title" :name="item.id">
        <div>
          {{ item.text }}
        </div>
      </el-collapse-item>
    </el-collapse>
  </div>
</div>
```